# MySQL SELECT based on second field value

Tags: mysql

I want to regroup my results based on the value of the second field.

I have the following table :

```
SELECT case_id, current FROM progress

+---------+---------+
| case_id | current |
+---------+---------+
|     158 |       1 |
|     158 |       1 |
|     165 |       0 |
|     165 |       0 |
|     166 |       0 |
|     166 |       1 |
|     166 |       0 |
+---------+---------+
```

And would like to regroup the case_id like this :

```
+---------+---------+
| case_id | current |
+---------+---------+
|     158 |       1 |
|     165 |       0 |
|     166 |       1 |
+---------+---------+
```

So if there are only '1', it will be a '1'.
If there are only '0', we get '0'. But if we have the 2 values but at least one '1' then it will be '1'.

I already tried to use `group` but it is not working as I expected.

I do not know what the most optimized way to get this working.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you are describing sounds like `max()`:

```
select case_id, max(current) as current
from t
group by case_id;
```